# What is the best way to keep deer away?

Tags: pest-control, pests

I've been contemplating putting up a fence, but I'm not exactly sure how high it should be.  Can anyone point me to some instructions on what specs a good deer fence should have as well as how to build it?

I have also seen motion sensor sprinklers that claim to scare deer away when they get too close.  Has anyone had any luck with these?  If it would work I would rather go this route.

Comment: (shotgun?) :-) sorry

Comment: @RoryAlsop lol yeah or a big hound dog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [article](http://icwdm.org/handbook/mammals/Deer.asp) goes into extensive details on electric fencing.  Fencing that is not electrified should be at least 8 feet tall. A detailed description is found [here](http://www.environment.gov.sk.ca/adx/aspx/adxGetMedia.aspx?DocID=309,301,254,94,88,Documents&MediaID=136&Filename=How%20to%20Build%20a%20Deer%20or%20Elk%20Proof%20Fence.pdf).  Sadly these solutions require time, money and a post hole digger or a tractor.

Deer pose a different problem for every gardener. A hungry deer will go to far greater lengths to eat your garden than ones that can survive on their normal diet.

You will also find suggestions to use bars of soap, human hair, dogs or getting a hunting licence. These will work for some deer, some of the time but if you want a solution for all of the deer, all of the time you need a fence.

Comment: +1 for electric fence. The deer discovered my garden last fall. I hadn't had a problem with them before then. I'm going with a solar electric fence. **However**, remember that an electric fence is a **psychological** barrier: the animal needs to be trained to fear the fence. The shock is "not that bad", and any determined animal will simply endure the brief pain to get to the food on the other side. (I've heard of raccoons charging the fence, throwing themselves through it to get to corn.) A hunting license only works if the deer come to your (rural!) garden, in season, during the day...